# Scala type bounding - no error being thrown?

Tags: scala

I'm currently trying to wrap my head around scala type bounds. It was my understanding that they are used to limit the types that can be used in generics based on the types' hierarchical relationship.

In my mind, the following code shouldn't work properly; testdef is taking two parameters which are neither sub nor superclasses of one another, and the bound B<:A should throw an error. But this isn't happening; this code runs just fine.

```
case class testclass1(val1: Int)
case class testclass2(val2: Int)

def testdef1[A, B <: A](a: A, b: B): (A, B) = {
  (a, b)
}

testdef1(testclass1(1), testclass2(2))
```

However, the following throws an error as expected, because testdef2 only takes testclass1 or any subtype of testclass1 (which testclass2 isn't):

```
def testdef2[A <: testclass1](a: A): A = {
  a
}
testdef2(testclass2(1))
```

So, why does the first example not enforce the relationship between the generics A and B (testclass1 and testclass2)?

Comment: Pasting that in the repl shows that the type returned by `testdef` is `(Product with Serializable, testclass2)` - maybe there's some hint there.

Comment: That's a really good catch... this must be more of an annotation than a restriction. I'll post something if I have something to follow up with.

Comment: Actually, if you look at `testclass1` as an instance of `Product` then `testclass2` *is* a subclass of `Product`.  It becomes even easier to see if you don't use case classes (you get an `(Object, SecondClass)` `Tuple2`).

Comment: If you really want to stick to the type bound: `def testdef1[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit env: B <:< A)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a generic method like `testdef1` the compiler will infer the most specific types for the type parameters that will still allow it to typecheck. Setting `A` to `testclass1` and `B` to `testclass2` gives them the most specific types that work with the passed-in parameters, but it doesn't typecheck because `B <: A` is violated. The compiler then generalizes the type parameters, and discovers that setting `A` to `Product with Serializable` is just enough to get it to typecheck. Basically it decides that:

```
testdef1(testclass1(1), testclass2(2))
```

Means:

```
testdef1[Product with Serializable, testclass2](testclass1(1), testclass2(2))
```

Now, where do `Product` and `Serializable` come from? All case classes are automatically made subtypes of these traits, and provided with appropriate method definitions. Because both `testclass1` and `testclass2` are case classes, `Product with Serializable` is the most specific type that is a supertype of both, technically called the least upper bound, or "lub". It's similar to the least common multiple for integers.

In fact, because the compiler could decide that `A` is `Any`, `testdef1` will typecheck no matter what is passed to it.

(Kudos to Daenyth for pointing out the `A` becomes `Product with Serializable`.)

Comment: This was a great explanation, thank you so much for your help; the subtlety of the typecasting would have taken me ages to figure out. Thank you!